# Pass collection of attributes as a Map to composite component attribute

Tags: jsf-2, dictionary, attributes, validation, composite-component

I want to pass a collection of attributes to composite component (jsf 2.2, Mojarra 2.2.4-jbossorg-1, running on WildFly 8 CR1). The number of attributes is random so I decide to use a reference to map in bean. Also I need a validator for the composite component. This validator will get these attributes to realizes the validation.

This is part of the implementation of composite component:

```
<h:inputText id="in" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" styleClass="form-control"               
   binding="#{cc.attrs.inputBinding}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}" 
   requiredMessage="#{cc.attrs.requiredMessage}">
   <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.placeholder}">
      <f:passThroughAttribute name="placeholder" value="#{cc.attrs.placeholder}"/>
   </c:if>
   <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.validatorId}">
      <f:validator validatorId="#{cc.attrs.validatorId}"/>
  <c:forEach var="attr" items="#{cc.attrs.validatorAttributes}">
     <f:attribute name="#{attr.key}" value="#{attr.value}"/>                        
  </c:forEach>
   </c:if>
</h:inputText>
```

In the interface of the composite component I declare the attribute for map in this way:

```
<cc:attribute name="validatorAttributes" required="false" type="java.util.Map"/>
```

When I 'am using the composite component I declare the refecnce to the map in this way:

```
validatorAttributes="#{bean.referenceNumberAttributeMap}"
```

I tried with map like:

```
<String, String> and <String, Object>
```

In the validator I get the attribute with this:

```
component.getAttributes().get("someKey")
```

It seems that for some reason the attributes are not added. If  I use c:forEach  outside the h:inputText I can print the map keys and values with h:outputText for example.